# How To Add Edit Mode To UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table that currently lets you swipe to delete.  I want to have an edit button in nav bar so that the user can change the cell's title text.

I have this so far but nothing happens

```
UIBarButtonItem * editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(setEditing:animated:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:editButton];
[editButton release];

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    if(editing)
    {
        NSLog(@"editMode on");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Done leave editmode");
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
     {
         // Delete the managed object for the given index path
         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
         [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
         NSLog(@"fetched results : \n%@\n",[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);

         // Commit the change.
         NSError *error = nil;

         // Update the array and table view.
         if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
         {
             // Handle the error.
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where are you implementing your edit button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just have or uncomment this on your `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

And implement

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
if(editing)
{
    NSLog(@"editMode on");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Done leave editmode");
}

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];

}
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything.  Same problem I'm having now.

Comment: I tried this but it crashed: -(void)toggleEdit
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];
    
    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

Comment: Yes I already have that and it works fine.  I had a button that pushes to another view so I know the navbar works.

Comment: If you have a navigation bar, ` self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;` SHOULD Work.

Comment: My table is loaded from FetchedResultsController, not sure if that maters.  Ok so the edit button works, it changes to done and back to edit, but it doesn't add the red minus sign to the cells.

Comment: This does not matter. If you have a navigation bar, then you can be fairly certain you can also add a button to it. Do not allocate your own `Edit` bar button item. Remove those, and use the ones in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Ok so the edit button works, it changes to done and back to edit, but it doesn't add the red minus sign to the cells.

Comment: Implement ` - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath `

Comment: It should appear.. Hm . What about `canEditRowAtIndexPath` ??

Comment: - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

Comment: I've added the full code here if you can take a quick look, thanks. https://gist.github.com/1096246

Comment: This worked for me - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    [self.routineTableView setEditing: !self.routineTableView.editing animated:YES];
    
    if (self.routineTableView.editing)
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    else
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
}

Comment: Well yeah. Thats the same. So you are all clear now ? No problems right ?

Comment: Yes, it works. But I want a button so that I can rename the cell.  How can I add this?  right now it just has the delete button on the left.

Comment: `- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: Actually forget the rename thing.  What I need is for the cells to be able to be movable instead.  Ideas?

Comment: ` - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
`

Comment: I already have this, but no luck - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}